# Remainders of polynomials of higher degrees.

Tags: polynomials

Let $R(x)$ be a remainder upon dividing $x^{44}+x^{33}+x^{22}+x^{11} +1$ by the polynomial $x^4 +x^3 +x^2 +x +1$. Find: $R(1)+2R(2)+3R(3)$. Answer provided is $0$

Comment: @JohnHughes I can't think how to deal with such a higher degrees.

Comment: Why would the degree pose a problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**
\begin{align}
  & {{x}^{55}}-1=({{x}^{11}}-1)({{x}^{44}}+{{x}^{33}}+{{x}^{22}}+{{x}^{11}}+1) \\ 
 & {{x}^{5}}-1=(x-1)({{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{2}}+{{x}^{1}}+1) \\ 
\end{align}
$$\frac{{{x}^{44}}+{{x}^{33}}+{{x}^{22}}+{{x}^{11}}+1}{{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{2}}+{{x}^{1}}+1}=\frac{{{x}^{55}}-1}{{{x}^{5}}-1}\times \frac{(x-1)}{({{x}^{11}}-1)}$$

Comment: Doesn't this mean the OP's expression is $0$?

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki, Would you mind adding a few steps more

Comment: ya, please add some more steps, please.

Comment: Good job, Behrouz! @labbhattacharjee This is the formula for [the cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $\Phi_{55}(x)$.

Comment: So Thanks @ Jyrki Lahtonen

Answer (score 5):

$$x^{44}+x^{33}+x^{22}+x^{11}+1=\frac{x^{55}-1}{x^{11}-1}=\frac{(x^5-1)\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^{5k}}{x^{11}-1}\\=\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^{5k}}{\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k}=(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)\cdot\color{blue}{\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^{5k}}{\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k}}$$

The blue fraction is actually a polynomial because the only eleventh root of $1$ which is also a fifth root of $1$ is $1$ itself. Or, if you prefer, because $\operatorname{gcd}(x^{11}-1,x^5-1)$ is obviously $x-1$.

Answer (score 4):

The thing that makes this easy is $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ divides $x^5 - 1$. Thus, if
$$\begin{align} f(x) &\equiv g(x) & &\pmod{x^5 - 1} 
\\ g(x) &\equiv h(x) & &\pmod{x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1} 
\end{align}$$
then
$$ f(x) \equiv h(x) \pmod{x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1} $$
and it's easy to find a low degree $g(x)$ to use as the intermediate, since $x^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{x^5-1}$.

---

But even without that, you can use the usual tricks for modular arithmetic; e.g. some of the content of [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand?noredirect=1&lq=1) applies here too.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\,\ (x\!-\!1)f\, =\, x^{\large 5}-1\,\ $ for $\,\ f =\, x^{\large 4}+x^{\large 3}+\cdots+1,\,\ $ therefore

$\qquad\quad \begin{eqnarray}{\rm mod}\ f\!:\,\ x^{\large \color{#c00}5}\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\  &&x^{\large 4+\color{#c00}5I}+\!&&x^{\large 3+\color{#c00}5J}+\!&&x^{\large 2+\color{#c00}5K}+\!&&x^{\large 1+\color{#c00}5L}+\!&&x^{\large\color{#c00} 5M}\\
\equiv\,\ &&x^{\large 4}\quad + &&x^{\large 3}\quad  + &&x^{\large 2} \quad + &&x\quad\  + &&1\,\equiv\, f\,\equiv\, 0\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Above we  used five times that $\ x^{\large A + \color{#c00}5B} = x^{\large A} (x^{\large \color{#c00}5})^{\large B}\equiv x^{\large A}(1^{\large B})\equiv x^{\large A}.\ $ Note that this method requires no knowledge of any special factorization formulas (except $\,(x\!-\!1)f = x^5-1),\,$ so it will work much more generally.

Answer (score 3):

Long division of $x^{44}+x^{33}+x^{22}+x^{11}+1$ by $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ gives a quotient of
$$
x^{40}-x^{39}+x^{35}-x^{34}+x^{30}-x^{28}+x^{25}-x^{23}+x^{20}-x^{17}+x^{15}-x^{12}+x^{10}-x^{6}+x^{5}-x+1$$
and no remainder. It is not a lot of work: only five lines.