# Let $P(x) =1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$. What is the remainder when $P(x^{12})$ is divided by $P(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(x) =1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$. What is the remainder when $P(x^{12})$ is divided  by $P(x)$?

Comment: should there be exponents?

Comment: When you work with higher degree polynomial and carry out multiplication and division you are not doing Linear Algebra.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1856104/11619).

Comment: Please improve your question by mentioning your attempts. There is an interesting interpolation approach related with the sixth roots of unity.

Comment: In particular, the remainder is $\color{red}{6}$ because the value of $Q(x)=P(x^{12})$ at any sixth root of unity is six.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** $$P(x) = \frac{x^6 - 1}{x-1}, \quad \text{when} \quad x \not = 1$$

Comment: Secondary hint: $a^2-b^2$